# Question regarding hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a bag with $A$ balls, out of them, $B$ are black.
What is the probabilty to get $n$ balls out until I get $m$ black ones? (without putting the balls back after each time)

I thought of using hypergeometric distribution but I think something is missing.

Comment: It's the case that you get out $m-1$ blacks in $n-1$ try, And finally, your last ball would be black.

Answer (score 1):

Your thought of using the hypergeometric distribution is correct, but you need to slightly adjust it to calculate the required probability. You should consider a sample of size $n-1$ and not $n$, determine the probability of $m-1$ black balls in the $n-1$ sample and then stipulate that the next ball will be black.

To that end, consider the number $X$ of black balls that are drawn which follows the hypergeometric with parameters

- $A=$ population size,
- $B=$ successes in the population,
- $n-1$ sample size.

Thus the probability of $x=m-1$ successes is equal to $$P(X=m-1)=\frac{\dbinom{B}{m-1}\dbinom{A-B}{n-1-(m-1)}}{\dbinom{A}{n-1}}$$ Now you need that the next ball is necessarily black. Observe that conditional on the event that you have drawn $m-1$ black balls in the $n-1$ first draws, in the bag there are

- $A-(n-1)$ balls in total,
- $B-(m-1)$ black balls

So the probability that the next ball will be black is equal to $$\frac{B-(m-1)}{A-(n-1)}$$ Combining the above, and by using [the product (or chain) rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29) the required probability is equal to $$P(X=m-1)\cdot\frac{B-(m-1)}{A-(n-1)}=\frac{\dbinom{B}{m-1}\dbinom{A-B}{n-m}}{\dbinom{A}{n-1}}\cdot\frac{B-(m-1)}{A-(n-1)}$$